# Doxygen Java comment attributes in same type declaration

Tags: java, attributes, doxygen

I have lots of attributes of the same type, so I declare them sepparated by commas.

I'm trying to do something like this

```
private Label percentLbl,       //!< @brief percent desc.
              versionLbl;       //!< @brief version desc.
```

percentLbl is documented as it should, but versionLbl is added as **Package attribute** insead of Private attribute.

Comment: Maybe set the `;` at the next line ?

Comment: @albert Sorry but what do you mean?

Comment: remove the `;` after `versionLbl` and put a `;` on next line.

Comment: @albert I'm still not getting the result I want, and an extra < is added in the documentation

Comment: It was just a wild guess. Which version of doxygen are you using? Please post a small complete MWE so we can test it more easily.